# Druid Cannot Connect to mysql metadata database after reinitialization

Tags: druid

I reconfigured my apache druid metadata store to mysql from derby.- But could not access the metadata database after.

## Druid web UI is showing:

"Could not load SQL metadata".

## Other druid log files are showing logs like:
coordinator-overlord.log:

2023-05-27T17:49:18,583 INFO [main] org.apache.druid.cli.CliCoordinator - Coordinator is configured to act as Overlord as well (druid.coordinator.asOverlord.enabled = true).
2023-05-27T17:49:18,792 INFO [main] org.apache.druid.guice.ExtensionsLoader - Loading extension [mysql-metadata-storage], jars: mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar, protobuf-java-3.21.9.jar
2023-05-27T17:49:24,911 INFO [main] org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.5.Final
2023-05-27T17:49:25,721 INFO [main] org.apache.druid.guice.ExtensionsLoader - Loading extension [mysql-metadata-storage], jars: mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar, protobuf-java-3.21.9.jar

## middleManager.log:

2023-05-27T17:50:50,057 INFO [main] org.apache.druid.guice.ExtensionsLoader - Loading extension [mysql-metadata-storage], jars: mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar, mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar, protobuf-java-3.21.9.jar
2023-05-27T17:50:55,743 INFO [main] org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.5.Final
2023-05-27T17:50:56,460 INFO [main] org.apache.druid.guice.ExtensionsLoader - Loading extension [mysql-metadata-storage], jars: mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar, mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar, protobuf-java-3.21.9.jar

Need help please.

Comment: I have gone past this stage. I reviewed the connect properties setting , made some changes. Also configured classpath in .bash_profile to include the lib location.

Comment: And restarted the services. And then i can see the error is gone. Also all the druid services are showing.  But another challenge now. All jobs are in pending state. Ive raised a saparate question for that. thank you